# PHP Facebook JSON convert tool to csv

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, csv

I'm trying to get data from Facebook into a spreadsheet and I'm using the code that follows but, I'm having some problems:

> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/tratajson.php on line 27

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
  $arquivo = fopen('/filepath.csv','w');
  $request_url ="/filepath.json";
  $requests = file_get_contents($request_url);
  $fb_response = json_decode($requests);

  foreach ($fb_response->feed->data as $item)
  {
    $mensagem=trim($item->message);    
    $mensagem = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n","(",")","chr(13)","\t", "\0", "\x0B"), "", $mensagem);   

    $quempostou=$item->from->name;  
    $data=$item->created_time;

    $ncomentarios=0;
    $nlikes=0;
    foreach ($item->comments as $comentarios)
    {
      $ncomentarios++;
      foreach ($comentarios as $comentario)
      {
        echo "Quem comentou:";
        echo $comentario->from->name;
        $comentou=$comentario->from->name;

        echo " Curtir:";
        echo $comentario->like_count;
        $curtidas=$comentario->likecount;
        $nlikes=$nlikes+$curtidas;

        echo " Data:";
        $datacomentario = $comentario->created_time;
        echo $datacomentario; 

        echo " Comentario:";  
        $comentario=$comentario->message;
                   $comentario = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n","(",")"), "", $comentario);   
        echo $comentario;

         $grava="COMENTARIO:".";".$comentario.";".$comentou.";".$datacomentario.";".$curtidas."\n";

        fwrite($arquivo,$grava);

        echo "<br>";    
      }
    }

    echo "Quem postou: $quempostou <br>";
    echo "Mensagem: $mensagem <br>";
    echo "Data: $data <br>";
    echo "Comentarios: $ncomentarios <br>";
    echo "Likes na thread: $nlikes <br>"; 
    echo "<br><br>";

    $grava="POST:".";".$mensagem.";".$quempostou.";".$data.";".$ncomentarios.";".$nlikes."\n\n";
    fwrite($arquivo,$grava);
  }
  fclose($arquivo);
?>
```

The file requested in $request_url has the structure of a JSON file returned in a FB Graph API explorer of a page feed:

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you post the sample JSON?

Comment: you can see here @AmalMurali :
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=stackoverflowpage%3Ffields%3Dfeed.limit(1)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this `$fb_response = json_decode($requests);` into this `$fb_response = json_decode($requests,true);`

Comment: with this change i get the following result:
   -PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/tratajson.php on line 10
   -PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/tratajson.php on line 10
   -PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/tratajson.php on line 10

Comment: and don't return any row in my spreadsheet, before i get the rows but, with some erros like tabulation and count erros in "likes" and "comments"